# Is there a Mongo query parser around for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm looking for something that can parse and manipulate Mongo queries similar to this:

https://github.com/intercom/mongo-parser-rb

but for JavaScript. The primary thing I'd like to do with something like this is search through values in queries, and replace `_id` strings with `ObjectIds` for specific fields.

An example of the type of interface I'm looking for:

```
var parsedQuery = parseQuery({
  _id: "32j9f328haff8jA", 
  $and: [
      $or:[{something:{$gt: 45}}, {somethingElse:{$lt:0}}], 
      {"stuff.ref_id":{$in: ["32j9f328haff8jB", "32j9f328haff8jC"]}}
  ]
})

var modifiedQuery = parsedQuery.mapValues(function(field, value) {
   var parts = field.split('.') // handle dot notation
   if(field === '_id') return ObjectId(value)
   else if(parts.slice(0,2).join('.') === 'stuff.ref_id) {
      if(parts.length === 2) { //  handles "stuff.ref_id"
         return ObjectId(value)
      } else if(parts.length > 2) {
         return value.map(function(v) {
           return ObjectId(v)
         })
      }
   } else {
      return value
   }
})

/* where modifiedQuery would be:
{
  _id: ObjectId("32j9f328haff8jA"), 
  $and: [
      $or:[{something:{$gt: 45}}, {somethingElse:{$lt:0}}], 
      {"stuff.ref_id":{$in: [ObjectId("32j9f328haff8jB"), ObjectId("32j9f328haff8jC")]}}
  ]
}
*/

var cursor = mongo.collection('whatever').find(modifiedQuery)
// etc
```

Does anything similar to this exist?

Comment: I've determined there isn't, and so I'm writing one. It's already partially finished, and I should have the query matcher done tomorrow: https://github.com/fresheneesz/mongo-parse

Comment: Your work is much appreciated!